# How to delete rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am having trouble deleting specific rows from my dataframe. I first collected the rows I wanted to delete and stored them in a variable and tried to drop them from the df, but I'm running into trouble. Can someone guide me?

```
n = ['NES', 'SNES', 'N64', '2600', 'PSV', 'SAT', 'WS', 'NG', 'TG16', 'GG', 'PCFX', '3DO', 'SCD', 'GB']
df_drop = df[df['platform'].isin(n)]
df = df.drop(df_drop, axis=0)
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-80322bccee93> in <module>
      2 n = ['NES', 'SNES', 'N64', '2600', 'PSV', 'SAT', 'WS', 'NG', 'TG16', 'GG', 'PCFX', '3DO', 'SCD', 'GB']
      3 df_drop = df[df['platform'].isin(n)]
----> 4 df = df.drop(df_drop, axis=0)


----
KeyError: "['name' 'platform' 'year_of_release' 'genre' 'na_sales' 'eu_sales'\n 'jp_sales' 'other_sales' 'critic_score' 'user_score' 'rating'\n 'total_sales'] not found in axis"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:
df[~df["platform"].isin(n)]
This will show the data frame masked where rows don't contain anything in list n

Comment: Only one question per post.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).